# android spinner options from JSON array

Tags: android, json, spinner, android-spinner, android-adapter

I'm trying to populate an android spinner data from a JSON string fetched from an external URL. The string is fetched fine and is successfully converted into array. But the spinner output is blank.

Thanks in advance.

Here are the codes:

**JSON**

```
{"bgroup":[
    {"id":"1","name":"A+"},
    {"id":"2","name":"B+"},
    {"id":"3","name":"AB+"},
    {"id":"4","name":"O+"},
    {"id":"5","name":"A-"},
    {"id":"6","name":"B-"},
    {"id":"7","name":"AB-"},
    {"id":"8","name":"O-"},
]}
```

**Layout XML:**

```
<Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bgrp_spinner"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.bapps_v1.b;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.showErrorDialogFragment;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy npolicy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();


    private String URL_GROUP = "http://127.0.0.1/test/blood_api/group.php";
    InputStream is;
    private static String presult = "";
    private static String tempstr = "";
    ArrayList<String> bgrpList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle AREQUEST = intent.getExtras();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(npolicy);
        JSONObject jsonResponse;


        bgrpList = new ArrayList<String>();




        try{
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rmail","blank"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rpass","blank"));
            try {
                InetAddress i = InetAddress.getByName(URL_GROUP);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL_GROUP);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error ClientProtocolException:  "+e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error IOException: "+e.toString());
        }


        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();

            presult= sb.toString();

            try{
                jsonResponse = new JSONObject(presult);
                JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("bgroup");
                int lengthJsonArr = jsonMainNode.length();


                for(int i=0; i < lengthJsonArr; i++)
                {
                    JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                    bgrpList.add(jsonChildNode.optString("name").toString());
                }

                Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.bgrp_spinner);
                mySpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        bgrpList));

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item ,bgrpList);
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinnerBlood.setAdapter(adapter);

            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void MapsActivity(View view) {
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
        try {
            if (status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                //boolean errdg= showErrorDialogFragment (status, this, int requestCode);

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setMessage("Play services not installed/out of date")
                        .setTitle(R.string.alert);


                builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // User clicked OK button
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert11 = builder.create();
                alert11.show();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Error: GooglePlayServiceUtil: ", "" + e);
        }

    }
}
```

**0utput screenshot with blank spinner**

---

[image: 0utput screenshot with blank spinner]

Comment: `the string is fetched fine and is successfully converted into array.` ... sure ... and the server is on the device/emulator(127.0.0.1) ...

Comment: @Selvin, yes... I've provided the output JSON for reference

Comment: @Selvin, you were right on point. The server was not in the device/emulator. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These were the problems:

**1. No new lines/tabs in JSON:** (`JSONObject` fails)

```
{"bgroup":[{"id":"1","name":"A+"},{"id":"2","name":"B+"},{"id":"3","name":"AB+"},{"id":"4","name":"O+"},{"id":"5","name":"A-"},{"id":"6","name":"B-"},{"id":"7","name":"AB-"},{"id":"8","name":"O-"}]}
```

**2. Local IP:**
The localhost/local IP not works (even if checked with `InetAddress`) for `httppost` in AVD